# Covering Indexes in NPGSQL ,.Net Core

Tags: npgsql

I am trying to include non-key column in my index using NPGSQL, .NET Core.

I have followed the example found here https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/indexes.html

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
=> modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
               .ForNpgsqlHasIndex(b => b.Id)
               .ForNpgsqlInclude(b => b.Name);
```

The example refers to "modelBuilder" but what is modelBuilder please (as it does not exist in the current context)?

I changed it to refer to the builder variable but it did not work as DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Entity' and no 'Entity' accepting argument 'Device' (Device exists).

I then changed it to refer to ModelBuilder type variable, it also did not work (No override of OnConfiguring(ModelBuilder ...)

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of EF Core provider for PostgreSQL do you use?
Check the entry in your `*.csproj` file.

It should be the **2.2.0** version as [this feature](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/2.2.html) is introduced in the 2.2.0.

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Hovever it seems that the docs have some mistake. Try to configure the indexes in the

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

If I manage to verify the results on my own I will let you know.

If the methods are still not visible and calling them inside the `OnModelCreating()` does not help try to [force restoring Nuget packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages).
If you use Rider you can do it via `Tools -> NuGet -> NuGet Force Restore`

**EDIT:** Check also  if your PostgreSQL version is [**11 (or higher)**](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-11-covering-indexes/)

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, the only version I can grab in Visual Studio is 2.1.2.  I am forcing it to download 2.2.0 now.